# When I use the .net chart to show the picture on a page it displays a page only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts

Hi，I'm using chart control in Mvc3 Application .

**controller code:**

```
Chart newChart = new Chart(800,600);
newChart.AddSeries(...)
newChart.AddSeries(...)
ViewBag.chart = newChart;
return View();
```

**View page**

```
@{ Layout = "~/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"}

@ViewBag.chart.Write()
...
```

However,the page only display the chart itself, the css is not working, the Content in the page are all missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

- An action that renders just the chart (your code appears to be one way to do this - `chart.Write()`) - e.g. Controller "ChartController" action "MyChart".

  Common ways to do this are to call `chart.Write` from a void Action method, or to save the chart data in a byte array or memory stream, and return a `FileResult` from the chart Action method.
- A View with an img whose source is the url of the action that renders the chart, e.g.

  ```
  ...
  <img asrc="@Url.Action("MyChart", "ChartController")" ... />
  ...
  ```

Comment: thank you very much ,  I call chart.Write from a void Action method and it works.

Comment: and here is the solution on http://www.asp.net: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart